# Onboard bluetooth/wifi not working on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero

I'm running on a Pi zero 1.3, and I cannot get the onboard wifi / bluetooth to work on either Stretch or Jessie.

```
hcitool dev
```

returns an empty devices list, and when I try

```
systemctl status hciuart.service
```

I get

```
hciuart.service - Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Mon 2017-10-16 18:07:53 UTC; 23s ago
       └─ ConditionPathIsDirectory=/proc/device-
tree/soc/gpio@7e200000/bt_pins was not met
```

I have no problems using a USB dongle for wifi on this setup, it's only the onboard bt/wf that's not working. I've found a bunch of discussions for "gpio@7e200000/bt_pins was not met", but nothing really pointing to a fix for the Zero. Anyone know anything about this? Seems a bit weird that this error exists on clean installs of both Jessie and Stretch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because PI Zero has neither onboard wifi nor bt.

[Here is the spec](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero/)

Comment: Ugh ... how stupid of me. I completely forgot that the Zero 1.3 preceded the Zero W 1.1, I was using the wrong Zero. Just shoot me.

Comment: Hilariously, I was just doing _exactly_ the same thing.